# Intersection of two lists in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a simple script that will list the contents found in two lists.  To simplify, let's use *ls* as an example.  Imagine "one" and "two" are directories.

```
one=`ls one`
two=`ls two`
intersection $one $two
```

I'm still quite green in Bash, so feel free to correct how I am doing this.  I just need some command that will print out all files in "one" and "two".  They must exist in both.  You might call this the "intersection" between "one" and "two".

Comment: Nothing here actually answers the question: how to intersect two *variables* in a Bash script.

Comment: Seems like a new question in my opinion, that question is clearly answered here.

Comment: An arguably more useful approach is in the near-duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312762/compare-difference-of-two-arrays-in-bash

Answer (score 351, accepted):

```
comm -12  <(ls 1) <(ls 2)
```

Comment: Can't believe I had no knowledge of `comm` until today. This just made my whole week :)

Comment: `comm` requires the inputs to be sorted. In this case, `ls` automatically sorts its output, but other uses may need to do this: `comm -12 <(some-command | sort) <(some-other-command | sort)`

Comment: DO NOT USE ls' output for anything. ls is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing ls' output with code are broken. Globs are much more simple AND correct: 
                ''for file in *.txt''. Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I just used this in an effort to find usages of a `public` method `error()` provided by a trait, in combination with `git grep`, and it was awesome! I ran `$ comm -12 <(git grep -il "\$this->error(" -- "*.php") <(git grep -il "Dash_Api_Json_Response" -- "*.php")`, and luckily I ended up with the name of the file only that contained the trait.

Comment: This is hilarious. I was trying to do some crazy stuff with awk.

Comment: For those who are wondering what 12 means:

-1              suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1),

-2              suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2),

-3              suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)

Comment: @DarraghEnright according to the OpenBSD [man page](http://man.openbsd.org/comm), "a comm command appeared in Version 4 AT&T UNIX".

Answer (score 91):

###### Solution with [`comm`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html)

`comm` is great, but indeed it needs to work with sorted lists. And fortunately here we use `ls` which from the [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html) documentation:

> By default, the output is sorted alphabetically, according to the locale settings in effect.

```bash
comm -12  <(ls one) <(ls two)
```

###### Alternative with `sort`

Intersection of two lists:

```
sort <(ls one) <(ls two) | uniq -d
```

Symmetric difference of two lists:

```
sort <(ls one) <(ls two) | uniq -u
```

###### Bonus

Play with it ;)

```
cd $(mktemp -d) && mkdir {one,two} && touch {one,two}/file_{1,2}{0..9} && touch two/file_3{0..9}
```

Comment: Instead of *complement*, I think that's what is usually called *symmetric difference*.

Answer (score 34):

Use the [`comm`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html) command:

```
ls one | sort > /tmp/one_list
ls two | sort > /tmp/two_list
comm -12 /tmp/one_list /tmp/two_list
```

"sort" is not really needed, but I always include it before using "comm" just in case.

Comment: It's good to include it since it does need to be sorted, and he only used ls as an example.

Answer (score 3):

A less efficient (than comm) alternative:

```
cat <(ls 1 | sort -u) <(ls 2 | sort -u) | uniq -d
```

Comment: If you are using Debian's /bin/dash or some other non-Bash shell in your scripts, you can chain commands' output using parentheses: `(ls 1; ls 2) | sort -u | uniq -d`.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer You should flag the name of the person you are replying to, otherwise it is assumed you mean me.

Comment: @nitrogen MikaëlMayer is correct - chainging `sort -u | uniq -d` does nothing, because the sort has removed the duplicates before uniq starts to look for them. I think you have not understood what my command is doing.

Comment: @Benubird I was not able to get your command `cat <(ls 1 | sort -u) <(ls 2 | sort -u) | uniq -d` to output anything either.  My command should read `(ls 1; ls 2) | sort | uniq -d`, without the `-u`, to show list intersection.  @MikaëlMayer was right that my original command was broken.

Comment: @nitrogen The reason why I'm using cat, is because I want this to be a generalizable solution, so that you can replace `ls` with something else, e.g. `find`. Your solution does not allow this, because if one of the commands returns two lines the same, it picks it up as a duplicate. Mine works even if the user wants to do `ls 1/*` and compare all files across subdirectories. Otherwise, yes, it works as well. It's possible mine is bash-specific.

Comment: If anyone is interested you can try my version of "comm" which I called "common". It does not need sorting and supports "-123"  switches just like "comm". https://github.com/toni-rmc/common

Answer (score 1):

Join is another good option depending on the input and desired output

```
join -j1 -a1 <(ls 1) <(ls 2)
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., why is it a good option? How is it different from `comm`? Why and when should it be used over `comm`? What is it supposed to do? Why options `-j1` and `-a1`? - why are they needed and what is their significance/meaning? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22977016/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: I'm not teaching a class. The questions you asked can be found in the manual for the command.