# Remove (not just unset) multiple strings from an array without knowing their positions

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

Say I have arrays

```
a1=(cats,cats.in,catses,dogs,dogs.in,dogses)
a2=(cats.in,dogs.in)
```

I want to remove everything from a1 that matches the strings in a2 after removing ".in" , in addition to the ones that match completely(including ".in").

So from a1, I want to remove cats, cats.in, dogs, dogs.in, but not catses or dogses.

I think I'll have to do this in 2 steps. I found how to cut the ".in" away:

```
for elem in "${a2[@]}" ; do 
    var="${elem}"
    len="${#var}"
    pref=${var:0:len-3}
done
```

^ this gives me "cats" and "dogs"

What command do I need to add to the loop **remove** each elem from a1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696055/intersection-of-two-lists-in-bash

Comment: Just use `unset`. This would leave indices like `0, 2, 3, 4, 6` & remove indices `1, 5` from `a1`. Then just run `a1=("${a1[@]}")`, to set these indices as `0..4`.

Comment: Also, on another note, the default separator in array, is white space, not comma.

Comment: I'm unclear on why your question title says "**remove (not just unset)**". What do you think is the difference, when dealing with elements of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I went with:

```
for elem in "${a2[@]}" ; do 
    var="${elem}"
    len="${#var}"
    pref=${var:0:len-3}

    #set 'cats' and 'dogs' to ' '
    for i in ${!a1[@]} ; do 
            if [ "${a1[$i]}" = "$pref" ] ; then
                a1[$i]=''
            fi

    #set 'cats.in' and 'dogs.in' to ' '
            if [ "${a1[$i]}" = "$var" ] ; then
                a1[$i]=''
            fi
    done
done
```

Then I created a new array from a1 without the ' ' elements

```
a1new=( )
for filename in "${a1[@]}" ; do
    if [[ $a1 != '' ]] ; then
        a1new+=("${filename}")
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Checkes whether a value is in an array.
# Usage: "$value" "${array[@]}"
inarray () { 
    local n=$1 h
    shift
    for h in "$@";do
        [[ $n = "$h" ]] && return
    done
    return 1
}

a1=(cats cats.in catses dogs dogs.in dogses)
a2=(cats.in dogs.in)
result=()

for i in "${a1[@]}";do
    if ! inarray "$i" "${a2[@]}" && ! inarray "$i" "${a2[@]%.in}"; then
        result+=("$i")
    fi
done

# Checking.
printf '%s\n' "${result[@]}"
```

If you only want to print the values to *stdout*, you might instead want to use `comm`:

```
comm -23 <(printf '%s\n' "${a1[@]}"|sort -u) <(printf '%s\n' "${a2[@]%.in}" "${a2[@]}"|sort -u)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the easiest way to solve this is with nested `for` loops:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a1=(cats cats.in catses dogs dogs.in dogses)
a2=(cats.in dogs.in)

for x in "${!a1[@]}"; do                # step through a1 by index
  for y in "${a2[@]}"; do               # step through a2 by content
    if [[ "${a1[x]}" = "$y" || "${a1[x]}" = "${y%.in}" ]]; then
      unset a1[x]
    fi
  done
done

declare -p a1
```

But depending on your *actual* data, the following might be better, using two separate for loops instead of nesting.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a1=(cats cats.in catses dogs dogs.in dogses)
a2=(cats.in dogs.in)

# Flip "a2" array to "b", stripping ".in" as we go...
declare -A b=()
for x in "${!a2[@]}"; do
  b[${a2[x]%.in}]="$x"
done

# Check for the existence of the stripped version of the array content
# as an index of the associative array we created above.
for x in "${!a1[@]}"; do
  [[ -n "${b[${a1[x]%.in}]}" ]] && unset a1[$x] a1[${x%.in}]
done

declare -p a1
```

The advantage here would be that instead of looping through all of `a2` for each item in `a1`, you just loop once over each array. Down sides might depend on your data. For example, if contents of `a2` are very large, you might hit memory limits. Of course, I can't know that from what you included in your question; this solution works with the data you provided.

NOTE: this solution also depends on an *associative array*, which is a feature introduced to bash in version 4. If you're running an old version of bash, now might be a good time to upgrade. :)