# how to search all git commits for changes involving multiple strings with certain restrictions on unchanged content?

Tags: git

The following will search commits for changes involving "foo":

```
$ git log -S foo
```

How can I:

- search for changes involving `foo` and `bar`
- ensure that the change occurred in a file containing both patterns, even if only one pattern was involved in the change
- include commits from archived and non-archived branches

###### Partial solution based on answer by @LeGEC

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $GITDIR

declare -a myhashes=($(git log --all --pretty=%H))

for myhash in "${myhashes[@]}";do
    declare -a myfiles=($(git diff --pickaxe-regex -S "foo|bar" --name-only $myhash))
    echo found "${#myfiles[@]}" files starting with ${myfiles[1]}

    # Files with Foo
    declare -a fwf=($(git grep -l -e foo $myhash -- $myfiles))
    # Files with Bar
    declare -a fwb=($(git grep -l -e bar $myhash -- $myfiles))

    # how to intersect fwf,fwb?
done
```

Comment: I need some advice on `intersect(fwf,fwb)`.  I tried a method suggested in this answer, but the results were very strange (I'm not a regex expert yet):  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22439016/1798351

Comment: I think you should turn the "how to do this intersection" into a separate question, probably including in it a link to this original question and a note that, yes, this is a bit of an XY problem and you're more interested in X than Y, but now you do have this here Y to solve, meanwhile consider X too. :-)

Comment: As for using `comm` to implement intersection: comm is fine at doing this but it needs its inputs to be collated, which might be a problem. I haven't thought much about solving Y here. Note that `comm` does not do regular expressions at all, it's just searching for lines that match, or don't.

Comment: @torek, those are insightful comments.  In general I agree that stackoverflow posts should address problems that are atomic in nature.  However I also think that, especially for beginners, posts that address X,Y problems can provide insight into how a modular solution should be constructed, which is an essential skill in the real world.

Answer (score 2):

- search for changes involving `foo` and `bar` :

If you add `--pickaxe-regex`, the argumet to `-S` will be treated as a regexp :

```
git log --pickaxe-regex -S "foo|bar"
```

(see "a note about `-S`" below)

- search for changes involving foo and bar :

you can use `git log` to list all potential commits, and then refine from there (see "About your second point" below)

- include commits from archived and non-archived branches :

simply add `--all` to `git log` :

```
git log --all --pickaxe-regex -S "foo|bar"
```

---

*About your first point :*
a note about `-S` :

`-S` spots commits that *change the number of lines* matching the pattern. So using `-S "foo|bar"` (with regexes on) would overlook a commit where one line containing `foo` is turned into one line containing `bar`.

If that's not what you wish, you may be looking for `-G`, or you may want to make something out of the output of the two commands `git log -S foo` *and* `git log -S bar`.

---

*About your second point :*

if you add `--pretty=%H` to your `git log` command, you will have, as an output, only a list of hashes, for all the commits that may interest you.

To list the *files within those commits* that may interest you, you may either add `--name-only` to the `git log` command, or take these commits one by one, and re-run them through `git diff --pickaxe-regex -S "foo|bar" --name-only <sha>`.

Once you have a list of target commits, and a list of file names for all commits, you can check the content of each file within its target commit to see if it has both `foo` and `bar` within its content.

You can for example use `git grep -l -e foo <sha> -- <list of files>` and `git grep -l -e bar <sha> -- <list of files>` and combine the outputs to see what files contain both patterns.

You may also want to check the content of each file *before the commit* ; e.g : do you want to keep a file where `foo` was changed to `bar` ?
If such is the case, `file` could contain only `bar` in the target commit (`<sha>`), and could contain only `foo` in the parent commit : `<sha>^` :

```
# you may want to check the content of target files in the parent commit :
git grep ... <sha>^
```

You will need some scripting on top of those git commands to get a complete solution.

Comment: thanks for the thoughtful answer, @LeGEC.  I've updated the OP with a partial implementation.  Any chance you could offer a suggestion to intersect in bash (some other stack solutions i tried eg. `comm` did not work)?

Comment: `comm` expects files as input, not variables. You can turn a variable into a "file" using : `comm -12 <(echo $fwf) <(echo $fwb)`

Comment: also : you can add `--pickaxe-regex -S "foo|bar"` to your initial `git log` command, this should greatly reduce the size of `myhashes` array -- and probably speed up the overall execution time

Comment: (to intersect in bash) : another option is to use grep : `echo $fwf | grep -Ff <(echo $fwb)`