# awk how to iterate over two different paths

Tags: bash, awk

I have two directories in `/home/`: `dirA` and `dirB`.

Files in `dirA`:

```
fileA.txt
fileB.txt
fileC.txt
```

Files in `dirB`:

```
fileA.yaml
fileB.yaml
fileC.yaml
```

Expected is:

```
suppose the -F with `.txt` and `.yaml` to print $1.
If file names match, print dirA_files == dirB_files

Then print in the output:

dirA_files fileA == dirB_files fileA
dirA_files fileB == dirB_files fileB
dirA_files fileC == dirB_files fileC
```

Suppose my current path is `/home/` and I'm going to run `awk` in `/home/`.

I think something like this via `bash` but I'm curious if `awk` can do this:

```
while read -r dirA_files
do
    while read -r dirB_files
    do
        if [ "$dirA_files" == "$dirB_files" ]
        then
            echo "dirA_files $dirB_files == dirB_files $dirB_files"
        done < <(find dirA -name '*.txt' -ls | awk '{print $11}' | sed -e 's|dirA/||g' | awk -F '.txt' '{print $1}')
    done < <(find dirB -name '*.yaml' -ls | awk '{print $11}' | sed -e 's|dirB/||g' | awk -F '.yaml' '{print $1}')
```

**Update 1**

If file names don't match, then print nothing. There's no need to do anything if they don't match.

Comment: and if filenames do not match ... don't print anything? print a different message? please update the question with this detail and if necessary an example data point

Comment: @markp-fuso yes, do nothing if they don't match. I'll update.

Comment: `find -ls | awk`? **Why?**

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want to find strings in common between two different streams, that's what comm is for.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just do two `find` calls into files and use `diff`?

Comment: OTOH, a lot of this question is underspecified. Do you want to compare _individual_ names? (That would explain why you're using `while read` loops). Do you want to compare _the whole stream at once_?

Comment: @TimRoberts, please not `diff`. It's built to calculate, well, _a diff_, which can be computationally expensive. Just comparing strings is much cheaper than building a patch to transform between them, which has some messy worst-case performance numbers. `cmp` for comparing the whole stream or `comm` for operating line-by-line makes more sense.

Comment: If what one is really trying to do is find names shared between both inputs: [Intersection of two lists in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696055/intersection-of-two-lists-in-bash)

Comment: BTW, `find -printf` lets you specify a format string that doesn't include the directory name in the first place; there's absolutely no reason to use something like `sed` to strip it out later.

Comment: @TimRoberts `wouldn't it be easier ...`: no, I'm going to do some text processing if the file names match, and not only using `diff`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I really appreciate your comments. I'm not just trying to find if names match, but I'm going to do the text processing if names match.

Comment: Right; you can read `comm`'s output (containing only the matching names) to do that processing.

Comment: It's funny that for over a quarter century we've been telling people not to parse the output of `ls` but to use `find` (or other) instead and now someone's added a `-ls` argument to `find` to make `find`s output look like the output of `ls` :-).

Comment: @EdMorton oh God:( I didn't know that:( I wasn't in the IT industry over that quarter. I came to the IT around 5 years ago.

Comment: FYI using `find dirA -name '*.txt'` would also find files under subdirectories which could lead to clashes with files with the same name in different subdirectories when you try to compare them later. If you don't have subdirectories or don't want to search in them, you then you can just do `printf '%s\n' dirA/*.txt` instead of using `find`.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks that was interesting. But since the files extensions are not same, I think I need to use find (like what markp-fuso answered).

Comment: @Saeed no, you don't. I think you misunderstood what I was saying. To see what I'm referring to, try `awk '{sub(".*/","")}1' <(printf '%s\n' dirA/*.txt) <(printf '%s\n' dirB/*.yaml)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE:** updated after OP's comment that files could have multiple periods (eg, `dom.fileA.com.(txt|yaml)`)

Setup:

```
$ mkdir -p dir{A,B}
$ touch dirA/file{A,B,C,X}.txt  dirA/dom.fileA.com.txt
$ touch dirB/file{A,B,C,Z}.yaml dirB/dom.fileA.com.yaml
```

We can eliminate each `find | awk | sed | awk` with a single `find`, eg:

```
$ find dirA -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\n'
dom.fileA.com.txt
fileA.txt
fileB.txt
fileC.txt
fileX.txt

$ find dirB -name '*.yaml' -printf '%f\n'
dom.fileA.com.yaml
fileA.yaml
fileB.yaml
fileC.yaml
fileZ.yaml
```

We can then feed these into a single `awk` (to replace OP's current nested `while / if` construct, eg:

```
awk '
           { sub(/[.][^.]*$/,"",$0) }
FNR==NR    { seen[$0]; next }
$1 in seen { print "dirA_files", $0, "== dirB_files", $0 }
' <(find dirA -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\n') <(find dirB -name '*.yaml' -printf '%f\n')
```

This generates:

```
dirA_files dom.fileA.com == dirB_files dom.fileA.com
dirA_files fileA == dirB_files fileA
dirA_files fileB == dirB_files fileB
dirA_files fileC == dirB_files fileC
```

Comment: `gsub(/\..*/,"",base)` and `sed 's/\..*//g'` should probably be `sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",base)` and `sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'` respectively to avoid tripping over `foo.bar.txt` (and the `g` just isnt needed)

Comment: I tested your answer but it has one issue. It seems it's not checking the whole name (I understood that `$0` checks the whole line. Please change the file names to `dom.fileA.com.txt` and `dom.fileA.com.yaml` (add `dom` before file name and `.com` before extension). It only shows `dom == dom`.

Comment: @Saeed answer updated; fwiw, you'll get more useful answers with samples that are more representative of your actual environment (eg, show a sample file name containing multilpe periods)

Answer (score 2):

[Intersection of two lists in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696055/intersection-of-two-lists-in-bash) demonstrates how to use `comm` to find lines in common between two streams. Applying this here:

```
$ mkdir -p dir{A,B}
$ touch dirA/file{A,B,C,X}.txt
$ touch dirB/file{A,B,C,Z}.yaml
```

```
while IFS= read -r entry; do
  echo "dirA_files $entry == dirB_files $entry"
done < <(
  comm -12 \
    <(find dirA -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\n' | sed -e 's@[.]txt$@@' | sort) \
    <(find dirB -name '*.yaml' -printf '%f\n' | sed -e 's@[.]yaml$@@' | sort)
)
```

What makes this better than the awk solution (in some scenarios) is that it can handle cases where your list of filenames is too large to fit in available memory. (`sort` can page out to disk, and all of `find`, `sed` and `comm` have bounded memory usage).

(BTW, the above code doesn't correctly handle filenames containing newline literals; a more cautious variant might either use GNU extensions to handle those names correctly, or modify the `find` lines to ignore such files).

Answer (score 2):

> curious if `awk` can do this

I would not select `awk` for that task, but if GNU `AWK` is only tool at your disposal you might find common names (ignoring extensions) following way, let
`dirA` hold following (empty) files

```
fileA.txt
fileB.txt
fileC.txt
fileD.txt
```

and `dirB` hold

```
fileA.yaml
fileB.yaml
fileC.yaml
fileE.yaml
```

then

```
awk 'ENDFILE{sub(/^.*\//, "", FILENAME);sub(/[.][^.]*$/, "", FILENAME);arr[FILENAME]+=1}END{for(i in arr){if(arr[i]==2){print i}}}' dir[AB]/*.*
```

gives output

```
fileA
fileB
fileC
```

Explanation: After processing each file, that is inside [`ENDFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html), I extract file name without extension from relative path by using [`sub` String Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), then I increase value in `arr` for given filename. When all files are processed I output such filename which appeared exactly 2 times.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0,)*

Answer (score 2):

Using any `awk` and the bash `printf` builtin:

```
$ printf '%s\n' dirA/*.txt dirB/*.yaml |
awk -F'/' '
    { sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"") }
    cnt[$2]++ { printf "dirA_files %s == dirB_files %s\n", $2, $2 }
'
dirA_files fileA == dirB_files fileA
dirA_files fileB == dirB_files fileB
dirA_files fileC == dirB_files fileC
```

The above works because:

1. You only want the files directly under `dirA` and `dirB`, so we can use `printf` instead of `find` and `printf` is a builtin so it won't fail even if the number of files exceeded `ARG_MAX`.
2. You can't have 2 files with the same base name (e.g. `fileA`) under either directory so the only way the count of base names can be greater than 1 is if that base appears in both directories.

Comment: Thanks sir, your answer's benefit over `markp-fuso`'s is what I said in the comments. I know I did not stated what I said, but your answer is better in this aspect.

Comment: You're welcome. FYI I didn't answer yesterday and I almost didn't answer at all, and I expect other people who had other ideas about possible solutions didn't answer, since you again accepted the first answer you got within 15 minutes of asking your question. As I've mentioned a few times now seeing a question with an accepted answer discourages other people from answering or even reading your question, and I'm not aware of any benefit to quickly accepting the first answer you get instead of waiting a few hours or a day and then accepting the best answer for you.

Comment: Yes you're right regarding accepting fast the best answer. I wasn't expecting this much gratitude from you and others, and I tried to be nice when that answer worked:( I hope I'll accept answers later.