# how to check if file names match and then if Nth column of both files match then print what don't match

Tags: bash, awk

This is `first` directory and its files:

`file1.some.thing.txt`:

```
forename: Saeed surname: 'Fazlollahzadeh'
forename: Joe surname: 'Smith Pleaser'
```

`file2.some.thing.txt`:

```
forename: Foo surname: 'Bar Ter'
forename: John surname: 'Smith'
```

This is `second` directory and its files:

`file1.some.thing.txt`:

```
forename: Joe surname: 'DB - Smith Pleaser'
forename: Saeed surname: 'DB - Fazlollahzade'
```

`file2.some.thing.txt`:

```
forename: Foo surname: 'DD - Bar'
forename: John surname: 'DD - Smith'
forename: Joe surname: 'DD - Swift'
```

Based on my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77398400/awk-how-to-iterate-over-two-different-paths) and different ways to check if file names match, I'm going to go through the files contents and check if:

1. find the forename from the first file (second column) in the second file (second column), then
2. if (`$4 to $NF` of `first` directory files) match (`$6 to $NF` of `second` directory files) match.

If the forename is found in another file, then it checks if surnames match too.

If it doesn't match, then it prints a message like:

```
file $first_file_name, no match forename $forename --> first surname: $first_surname || second surname: $second_surname
```

Based on different methods of last questions, I was trying to mix them with this `awk` code. These are my failed attemtps. Both of these codes prints only files names:

```
awk '
           { sub(/[.][^.]*$/,"",$0) }
FNR==NR    { seen[$0]; next }
$1 in seen
            { a[FNR] = $2; next }
{ if ($2 == $2)
if ($4 == $4)
print "matched: " $0
else print "unmatched: " $0 }
' <(find first -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\n') <(find second -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\n')
```

```
printf '%s\n' first/*.txt second/*.txt |
awk -F'/' '
    { sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"") }
    cnt[$2]++ { { a[FNR] = $2; next }
{ if ($2 == $2)
if ($4 == $4)
print "matched: " $0
else print "unmatched: " $0 } }
'
```

Expected output is:

```
file file1.some.thing, no match forename Saeed --> first surname: Fazlollahzadeh || second surname: Fazlollahzade
file file2.some.thing, no match forename Foo --> first surname: Bar Ter || second surname: Bar
```

Comment: will *all* surnames be wrapped in single quotes? could any of the forenames be wrapped in single quotes and/or include embedded spaces?

Comment: @markp-fuso yes they're all wrapped in single quotes. None of forenames are wrapped between quotes (neither single, nor double), and they don't contain any white spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your desired output format but here's a start at least, using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    # $1=$1     # <- uncomment this to change every chain of white space chars to a single blank char if you want to ignore white space differences.
    dir = file = FILENAME
    sub("/[^/]+$","",dir)
    sub(".*/","",file)
}
dir1 == "" {
    dir1 = dir
}
dir == dir1 {
    dir1vals[file FS $0]
    next
}
{
    sub(/\047([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2}/,"\047")
    if ( (file FS $0) in dir1vals ) {
        print "matched:", file, $0
    }
    else {
        print "unmatched:", file, $0
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk first/* second/*
matched: file1.some.thing.txt forename: Joe surname: 'Smith Pleaser'
unmatched: file1.some.thing.txt forename: Saeed surname: 'Fazlollahzade'
unmatched: file2.some.thing.txt forename: Foo surname: 'Bar'
matched: file2.some.thing.txt forename: John surname: 'Smith'
unmatched: file2.some.thing.txt forename: Joe surname: 'Swift'
```

The above assumes you don't have so many files as to exceed `ARG_MAX`. If you do have that many files then add this to the top of the awk script:

```
BEGIN { ARGC=2; ARGV[1]="-" }
NR == FNR { ARGV[ARGC++]=$0; next }
```

and then run it as:

```
printf '%s\n' first/* second/* | awk -f tst1.awk
```

so it reads the list of input files from stdin rather than them being passed as arguments. `printf` is a builtin and so is not limited to `ARG_MAX` args.

P.S. this:

```
    if ( (file FS $0) in dir1vals ) {
        print "matched:", file, $0
    }
    else {
        print "unmatched:", file, $0
    }
```

could be written more briefly as:

```
    print ((file FS $0) in dir1vals ? "" : "un") "matched:", file, $0
```

but I made the "if-else" explicit for clarity.

Comment: Just a question regarding `printf '%s\n' ...`, is it going to compare `file1` to `file2`? Or before the `if`s in `awk`, you're telling `awk` to check if file names match then do the `if` block?

Comment: The `printf` just prints all the file names. Try it on it's own. I'm not comparing file names alone in the awk script, I'm comparing the file name + current line contents - hence `val = file FS $0`. There's no reason to compare file names as a separate step when you want to check if `first/foo` and `second/foo` both contain `bar`. So when I read the `bar` line from `first/foo` I populate `dir1vals[foo bar]` and then when I read the `bar` line from `second/foo` I check if `foo bar` exists as an index of `dir1vals[]` (i.e. do a hash lookup).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer. Regarding `ARG_MAX` I couldn't find the value in my server. I think each directory has around 10 files because my current server is an ansible server and I run a command to get the output of other servers, then process them. I don't think it reaches the `ARG_MAX` although I don't know how to find its value in the server. It's Ubuntu if matters.

Comment: 10 files will be fine as long as they don't have massively long names. The first hit I got from [googling "ubuntu" ARG_MAX](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ubuntu%22+ARG_MAX) is https://askubuntu.com/questions/14081/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-command-line-arguments-in-gnome-terminal where I see an answer that tells me to use `getconf ARG_MAX`. Does that work for you? Looks like `xargs --show-limits` also will tell you "POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system)" which is the value of ARG_MAX.

Comment: Thanks, I googled before asking but I did not understand its meaning. I don't know if in the real server it reaches this maximum or not. I ran `getconf ARG_MAX` in one server and it is `2097152`. My real files sizes are between 1KB to 300KB.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the size of the files, it's the length of the string that consists of all of the arguments being passed to a command. So with `ls foo bar` the length of the arguments is the length of the sting "foo" plus the length of the string "bar" plus, presumably, the length of the blank char between them, i.e. 7 chars total. Since 7 is less than 2097152 that command line won't exceed ARG_MAX.

Comment: Oh I think I got. The max arguments of a command:) But I have other questions regarding this about when I run a bash script, is each command an argument of `bash`? For example one `read`, one `echo`, one `awk` like above and one `mail`, and each one has a lot of args. Does this mean max args for each one? E.g max args of `read`, then max of `echo`. Or it means the whole args of `bash`?

Comment: You hit the nail on the head when you said "I have other questions" :-). Please ask those other questions as questions.

Comment: How may I thank you Ed? Like any links to purchase a coffee? Any crypto wallet to transfer you Tether or Tron? I'm from Iran and I can use only cryptos since it has nothing to do with any govs in the world (I hope).

Comment: That sounds great, thanks.