# Compare user defined list to another list in bash

Tags: bash, psql

I am using psql to get a list of databases already running on my machine and a user-defined variable which has a list of database names. How can I check if the user-defined variables contain names that are already existing as a database?
Here Is what I have done so far but the results are not consistent

```
x=`psql -l | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v "+" | grep -v "Name" | grep -v "List" | grep -v "(" | grep -v "template" | grep -v "postgres" | grep -v "|" | grep -v ":"`
db_name=test1,test2
array=(${x})
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    for db in $(echo ${db_name} | tr ',' ' '); do
    if [[ ${i} != ${db} ]] ; then
        echo ${db} "Does not exists"  
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create two arrays and then obtain their intersection as in [Array intersection in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870230/array-intersection-in-bash)

```
sqlist=($(psql -l | awk '$1 !~ /[+(|:]|Name|List|template|postgres/ {print $1}'))
userlist=(test1 test2)

intersection=()
for sqitem in "${sqlist[@]}"; do
    for usitem in "${userlist[@]}"; do
        if [[ $sqitem = $usitem ]]; then
            intersection+=("$sqitem")
        fi
    done
done
printf '%s\n' "${intersection[@]}"
```

Notice also the simplification of the [useless uses of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) you had in your original `psql` postprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DB_LIST=$(psql -l | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v "+" | grep -v "Name" | grep -v "List" | grep -v "(" | grep -v "template" | grep -v "postgres" | grep -v "|" | grep -v ":")

for DB_NAME in test1 test2
do
    DB_COUNT=$(echo $DB_LIST|grep $DB_NAME|wc -l)
    if [ $DB_COUNT -eq 1 ]; then 
        echo $DB_NAME exists
    fi
done
```

Comment: You want simply `if echo "$DB_LIST" | grep -Fq "$DB_NAME"; then echo "$DB_NAME exists; fi`inside the loop. Also don't use uppercase for private variables.

Comment: I like your suggestion.
You have a typo in your one liner:
"$DB_NAME
Should be:
"$DB_NAME"