# Compare three arrays in bash, diff and identical values

Tags: arrays, bash, compare, diff

This question refers to the answered question: 
[Compare/Difference of two arrays in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312762/compare-difference-of-two-arrays-in-bash)

Let's take two arrays:

```
Array1=( "key1" "key2" "key3" "key4" "key5" "key6" "key7" "key8" "key9" "key10" "key13" )
Array2=( "key1" "key2" "key3" "key4" "key5" "key6" "key11" "key12" "key13" )
```

Symetrical Differences between arrays:

```
Array3=(`echo ${Array1[@]} ${Array2[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u `)
```

Array3 values:

```
echo $Array3
key10
key11
key12
key7
key8
key9
```

Values only in Array1:

```
echo ${Array1[@]} ${Array3[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -D | uniq
key10
key7
key8
key9
```

Values only in Array2

```
echo ${Array2[@]} ${Array3[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -D | uniq
key11
key12
```

My question, how can we get values that are in Array1 & Array2 but not in Array3 (identical)?
Expected result:

```
key1
key13
key2
key3
key4
key5
key6
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That code for symmetrical difference breaks if the arrays contain data they were designed to contain: elements that contain whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK after few test, it seems the answer I was looking for was just:

```
echo ${Array1[@]} ${Array2[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -D | uniq
key1
key13
key2
key3
key4
key5
key6
```

Comment: This breaks with elements containing spaces, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using :

```
#!/bin/bash

Array1=( "key1" "key2" "key3" "key4" "key5" "key6" "key7" "key8" "key9" "key10" "key13" )
Array2=( "key1" "key2" "key3" "key4" "key5" "key6" "key11" "key12" "key13" )

Array3=(`echo ${Array1[@]} ${Array2[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u `)

intersections=()

for item1 in "${Array1[@]}"; do
    for item2 in "${Array2[@]}"; do
        for item3 in "${Array3[@]}"; do
            if [[ $item1 == "$item2" && $item1 != "$item3" ]]; then
                    intersections+=( "$item1" )
                    break
            fi
        done
    done
done

printf '%s\n' "${intersections[@]}"
```

Output :

```
key1
key2
key3
key4
key5
key6
key13
```

Comment: Hi @arzyfex. Thanks for your answer but it don't work if my diff Array3 is empty. I can add a condition if Array3 is empty. Can we do the same thing with the echo style provided in Array3 ?