# Remove value from array bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I need help with bash.
I have two array:

```
Array1=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
Array2=(2 5 7)
```

I need remove items from array1 which are in Array2. Result should be

`Array3=(1 3 4 6)`.

Comment: read the answers in referenced questions.

Comment: I can see another similar question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312762/compare-difference-of-two-arrays-in-bash

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate, but [BashFAQ #36](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036) is also relevant.

Comment: One should also consider using associative arrays to avoid the need to recurse -- the O(n*m) performance characteristics of the code given in the self-answer is really quite horrid.

Comment: Aside: Answering your own question is welcome here, but answering your own question *by editing that answer into the question itself* is not. This "privileges" answers, such that they can't be voted or commented on separate from the question itself, and prevents mechanisms for putting good answers first from being effective.