# Compare and discard elements from array in bash

Tags: bash

I have two sorted arrays
`list1=( a b c d)`
`list2=( a b d)`

Suppose list1 is a constant list and list2 is created during script execution. I want to compare list2 elements with list1 and discard only those values from list2 which are not there in list1.

Example:
if `list2=(a b d e f)`, then I should update list2 as `list2=(a b)`as `(d e f)` isn't there in list1.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Inian I took help from some of the other array comparisons related questions, but couldn't able to achieve what I intended.

Comment: can the actual array contents contains spaces?. Also post whatever half efforts you made so far.

Comment: Did you look at [Compare/Difference of two arrays in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2312762/5291015)

Comment: Yes @Inian I referred this. Was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1=( a b c d)
list2=( a b d)
list2=($(echo ${list1[*]} ${list2[*]} | tr " " "\n" |sort | uniq -d))

echo ${list2[*]}
```

Here I convert the 2 lists to strings, separate by white space, sort the values and then find duplicates. The duplicates are then reassigned to the `list2` array

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any way I can find if ```list2``` is having any elements which is not there in ```list1```. For example, let ```list2=( a b e )``` then it should return ```[e]``` or simple Boolean flag sayng ```False``` as ```[e]``` is not there in ```list1```

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana, given that your original list2 and new list2 could be same or different, you should be able to determine this boolean flag yourself. Give it a try.