# Iterate over the array searching for multiple elements in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
firstvar="PRIMARY"
secondvar="SECONDARY"
thirdvar="TERTIARY"

array=($firstvar $secondvar $thirdvar)
echo ${array[*]} //prints PRIMARY SECONDARY TERTIARY
```

I want to iterate over this array in my bash script, and check if the 3 elements `(PRIMARY SECONDARY TERTIARY)` are present in the array with no specific order.
If yes, `echo "Success.` If not, `echo Failed`. What would be a good way to approach this?

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that if an element(e.g. PRIMARY) is missing from the array, it should also print out `Primary is missing.`
For a similar array:

```
array_health=($firsthealth $secondhealth $thirdhealth)
```

These 3 variables can have either 1 or something else
I want to check whether these 3 variables in the array have value=1, how would I check that? They're not initialized as `firsthealth=0` or `firsthealth=1`.

Comment: @dawg No. because that's the difference if arrays, I don't want that. I just want to check whether strings "PRIMARY" "SECONDARY" "TERTIARY" are in my array.

Comment: *echo ${array[\*]} | grep -w $firstvar | grep -w $secondvar | grep -qw $thirdvar && echo yes || echo no*

Comment: @alecxs: Gives a wrong answer if `"PRIMARY SECONDARY"` is in the array.

Comment: @alecxs Will this also echo yes, if one of the elements in the array is "PRIMARY IS DOWN" and I'm using "grep -w "PRIMARY"? Like if the substring matches would it print yes or no?

Comment: the way you have declared array doesn't allow whitespaces - so no, just iterate over array and do a case check instead

Comment: @alecxs I forgot to mention that if one of the elements in missing in the array, then it should print out which element is missing. How would I do that using your grep method

Comment: Don't ask two different questions in one question. It makes it hard for people to answer. Also, if you add a question later, it makes all the existing answers incomplete.

Comment: The answers at [Compare/Difference of two arrays in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2312762/8593689) should really do what you need. You can get the difference, and that difference would tell you which items were missing.

Comment: @choroba right, didn't see whitespaces in original question

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the elements one by one:

```
flag=0
for ele in "$firstvar" "$secondvar" "$thirdvar"; do
    if [[ ! " ${array[@]} " =~ " ${ele} " ]]; then
        echo "$ele" is missing
        flag=1
    fi  
done    


if [[ flag -eq 0 ]]; then 
    echo "all there"
fi
```

If there is a possibility that your elements may have spaces, that will make the test above unreliable. You can use a different delimiter by using `printf` to add left and right  delimiters to characters unlikely to be in your strings:

```
firstvar="PRIMARY SECONDARY"
secondvar="SECONDARY"
thirdvar="TERTIARY"

array=("$firstvar" "$thirdvar")

flag=0
printf -v tgt "|%s|" "${array[@]}"  # |ele1||ele2||eleN|
for ele in "$firstvar" "$secondvar" "$thirdvar"; do
    if [[ ! "$tgt" =~ "|${ele}|" ]]; then
        echo "$ele" is missing
        flag=1
    fi  
done    

if [[ flag -eq 0 ]]; then 
    echo "all there"
fi
```

Prints `SECONDARY is missing`

Comment: Gives a wrong answer if "PRIMARY SECONDARY" is in the array.

Comment: @choroba: fixed that...

Comment: Now it fails for `"|PRINARY|SECONDARY|" "TERTIARY"`...

Comment: It is clearly stated 'delimiters unlikely to be in your strings' so why would you then pick stings with those delimiters in them? I am not seeing how `"TERTIARY"` is failing at all...

Answer (score 1):

Try bash rematch

```
[[ ${array[@]} =~ $firstvar ]] && [[ ${array[@]} =~ $secondvar ]] && [[ ${array[@]} =~ $thirdvar ]] && echo ok || echo ko
```

Then like this

```
for item in $firstvar $secondvar $thirdvar; { 
    [[ ${array[@]} =~ $item ]] && echo "$item" || echo "$item is missing"
}
```

Comment: How would this print out which element is missing? I edited the question! sorry I forgot to mention that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

beginner friendly simple loop with simple case counting all vars
followed by test concatenation and simple if statement

```
array=("$firstvar" "$secondvar" "$thirdvar")

for i in "${array[@]}"
  do
    echo "$i"
    case "$i" in
      "$firstvar")
        first=$((first+1))
      ;;
      "$secondvar")
        second=$((second+1))
      ;;
     "$thirdvar")
        third=$((third+1))
      ;;
    esac
done

if [ "$first" ] && [ "$second" ] && [ "$third" ]
  then
    echo "Success."
  else
    [ -z "$first" ] && echo "'$firstvar' missing"
    [ -z "$second" ] && echo "'$secondvar' missing"
    [ -z "$third" ] && echo "'$thirdvar' missing"
fi
```

---

regarding your second array basically same, quote your vars
(although it's unclear to me how you want preserve labels as you only have values in array)

```
array_health=("$firsthealth" "$secondhealth" "$thirdhealth")
```

uninitialized vars can be [test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test)'ed with `-z` (as above) or have default value with [string manipulation](https://www.linuxnix.com/linuxunix-shell-scripting-10-string-manapluation-examples)

```
[ -z "$i" ] && echo "${i:-0}"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-dimensional arrays in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233825/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-bash)